# Insert html tag in string in php

Tags: php, html

I am new to `PHP` and while working on a project I face a problem.
I have the following string `Mango, Orange, Banana`

Now I tried using `str_replace(',', '<br/>',$string)` to replace the coma with the html tag `<br>` but I get this result `Mango<br/> Orange<br/> Banana` instead of

```
Mango
Orange
Banana
```

How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: How do you echo your string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on where are you going to display the results.

**In HTML page**: then you should use the appropriate HTML markup around `<br>` tags. This will tell browser to apply the default styles to your text (margins, line-breaks, etc).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php echo str_replace(',', '<br>', 'Mango, Orange, Banana'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Anywhere else**: then you should use the line break symbol. Different systems uses [different symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) for line-break, but hopefully PHP has the [pre-defined constant](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) `PHP_EOL`, that contains the line-break symbol.

```
<?php
    echo str_replace(',', PHP_EOL, 'Mango, Orange, Banana');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the str_replace works just fine, but the problem seems to be displaying html properly.

I tested using the following code, and it worked just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $data = 'Mango, Orange, Banana';
        $data = str_replace(',', '<br/>', $data);

        echo $data;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to put the content inside html -> body tags